# How to configure nodejs app to run via systemd on CentOS7?

Tags: centos, systemd

I created a folder for my nodejs app under my home folder.

```
/home/user/nodeapp
```

I think I installed node logged in as me.

which node gives me

```
/apps/node/bin/node
```

I can successfully run the app from my home folder using the command

```
node /nodeapp/server.js
```

I want to run the app as a service via systemd

Here is my systemd service file

```
[Service]
#Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=node-myapp
User=username
Group=username
Environment=HOME=/home/username/nodeapp/
Environment=NODE_PATH=/home/username/nodeapp/
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
ExecStart=/apps/node/bin/node /home/username/nodeapp/server.js

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service however fails to start and service enters a FailedState.

```
systemstc status -l node-myapp does not reveal anything.
```

How do I determine the cause for the service entering failed state? Nothing in the app.log file.

Comment: errors can be found via "journalctl -xe" - or "journalctl -xe | grep node-myapp" (did you start the service: systemctl start node-myapp? in order to load automatically you need to do a "systemctl enable node-myapp"...)

Comment: @MichaelD. Yes, the service was enabled. and journalctl does not reveal additional details other than saying app entered a failed state.

Comment: Change the service to this ExecStart=/apps/node/bin/node /home/username/nodeapp/server.js 2>&1 >>/var/log/myapp.log  -  restart service then check the contents of the log (tac /var/log/myapp.log)